# CSV via PHP repeat the first entry

Tags: php, csv

I have the following codes

```
<?php
if (($handle = fopen("cat.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {           
        if (isset($data[0])) {
            echo $data[0] . "<br>\n";
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
?>
```

and it prints the categories from the CSV file as seen below:

```
Main Category

Sub Category1

Sub Category2

Sub Category3

Sub Category4
```

What I need to achieve is to get the main category one more time to add the codes. How can I manage it?

```
Main Category Sub Category1

Main Category Sub Category2 

Main Category Sub Category3

Main Category Sub Category4
```

I have been checking every detail for the last few hours but I'm missing something. Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your cat.csv file is laid out as following:

```
Main Category,Sub Category1,Sub Category2,Sub Category3,Sub Category4
```

The below code should do the trick. If you make the main category for each row the first column, it will print out correctly.

```
<?php
    // Open your CSV File.
    $FileHandle = FOpen("cat.csv", "r");
    // Initiate a counter to count the ROWS of the file.
    $RowCtr = 1;
    // Create an empty variable to hold your prefix ("Main Category").
    $Prefix = "";
    // Verify the file is open.
    If ($FileHandle !== FALSE) {
        // Loop through the CSV file.
        While (($Data = FGetCSV($FileHandle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
            // Count the number of Columns.
            $ColCtr = COUNT($Data);
            // Add another row the ROW counter.
            $RowCtr++;
            // Loop through each column.
            For ($c = 0; $c < $ColCtr; $c++) {
                // If first iteration, save the value to the prefix for later use.
                If ($c == 0) {
                    $Prefix = $Data[$c];
                    // Echo $Data[$c] . "<br />";   // Uncomment this line to print the Main Category by itself first.
                } Else {
                    // Echo out the prefix with the new values.
                    if (!Empty($Data[$c])) {
                    Echo $Prefix . " " . $Data[$c] . "<br />";
                    }   
                }
            }
        }
        // Close the file.
        FClose($FileHandle);
    } Else {
        // Handle case if file cannot be opened.
    }
?>
```

This will print out

```
Main Category Sub Category1
Main Category Sub Category2
Main Category Sub Category3
Main Category Sub Category4
```

If your CSV looks like the following

```
Main Category,Sub Category1,Sub Category2,Sub Category3,Sub Category4
Main Category2,Sub Category5,Sub Category6,Sub Category7,Sub Category8
```

It will print out

```
Main Category Sub Category1
Main Category Sub Category2
Main Category Sub Category3
Main Category Sub Category4
Main Category2 Sub Category5
Main Category2 Sub Category6
Main Category2 Sub Category7
Main Category2 Sub Category8
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have converted column data fields to row data fields so it's working almost perfect but I have one other small issue. How to skip the empty parts? Please, see my second comment/answer on the page

Comment: Sourround if if/else block inside of the for loop with if (!Empty($Data[$c]) { }